# Getting the following error when trying to register using auth for my site in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, html, laravel-5

> BadMethodCallException in Validator.php line 1096: Method
>   [validateRequried] does not exist.

Here is my RegisterController.php file. I think I've added all the fields name there!!!

[image]

Comment: please just paste your code, instead of screenshotting it

Comment: Sure next time, I'll do it... Just cleared it now... It was the only spells mistake... !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo on line `52`

It should be `required` instead of `requried`

```
'lname' => 'required|string|max:255'
```